# Get IP address from a String(Groovy)

Tags: groovy, ip-address

I want to extract the IP and return it . Something like

```
def getIPfromString ( myString ) {

  ..
  return IP 
}

IP = getIPfromString("ftp://192.168.13.108/720_prev")
print " IP Address : " + IP
```

Output :

```
IP Address : 192.168.13.108
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Java's URL class with a dash of Groovy magic ;-)

```
String getAddressFromString( String url ) {
  url.toURL().host
}

String ip = getAddressFromString( 'ftp://192.168.13.108/720_prev' )

println "IP Address : $ip"
```

which (as requested) outputs:

```
IP Address : 192.168.13.108
```

Comment: This seems to work for `http:` or `ftp:`, but when I try to use it for an `ssl:` url I get:

`Caught: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: ssl`

I don't think the toURL() method recognizes ssl protocol URLs.

Answer (score 5):

If The URL already has the IP address then converting to a URL works to extract the IP but if a domain host name (e.g. www.stackoverflow.com) is found in the URL host component then need to perform a DNS lookup that resolves to an address. This requires a call to *InetAddress.getByName()* in the Java API.

If the URL already has the address then *InetAddress.getByName()* will simply return the address as-is. Also, need to address handling of exceptions if host name cannot be resolved to an address.

```
        String getAddressFromString( String url ) 
         throws MalformedURLException, UnknownHostException
        {
          String host = url.toURL().host
          // this would be equivalent to calling new URL(url).getHost()
          return InetAddress.getByName(host).getHostAddress()
        }

        String ip = getAddressFromString( "http://stackoverflow.com/" )
        println "IP Address : $ip"
```

Output:

```
IP Address : 69.59.197.21
```